# Trying to create a temp username password for Azure website using Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I've published a site to a Azure url and now I want to create a login page where a user has to enter in a username and password to get to the site. I don't want to use Facebook or another service. I just want a simple username/password I can distribute to the person I want to show the site too.

So, in App Services I select Authentication / Authorization, but I'm not sure what I have to do with the 'corresponding SSL bindings' I don't have any custom domains yet!

[image]

And then once I click on Azure Active Directory I see this

[image]

but now where do I enter in a username / password ?
I'm a little confused as to what I need to do to proceed!
Clicking on both manage application and manage permissions doesn't seem to take me to any page to create a temp username / password.

Answer (score 0):

If you configure your Azure web app to use Azure Active Directory login, only the user in your Azure AD tenant can login your web app. For more details, please refer to the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication). Regarding how to add user in Azure AD, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-users-azure-active-directory).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the user in Azure Active Directory. use Create User and that user will be able to login to your website

Comment: I can't seem to add a new user! if I try and use a domain name in the user name field, I see a red flag that says 'blah blah is not a verified domain name in this directory' I guess I only have the 'default directory' created but not sure if I need another one?

Comment: The domain name will be available in Overview window of Default Directory. should be something like xxxx.onmicrosoft.com. Create a user like abc@xxx.onmicrosoft.com

Comment: so if I wanted to create a user like 'test@mycustomurl.com' what would I have to do? Would I have to create a new directory?

Comment: You add and verify your custom domain in Azure AD and create user as test@mycustomurl.com